# Why umem_alloc suppose to be better than malloc?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, libumem

I read `libumem` is superior than standard `malloc`.

Both provide `malloc` and `free`, but I can see there is a function called `umem_alloc`.

I have hard time to understand the difference between `umem_alloc()` and `malloc()`.
Why `umem_alloc` suppose to be better than `malloc`?

Comment: libumem is originally a Solaris thing. It's a library used for dynamic analyzing and detection of memory misuse, afaik.

Comment: "I read" Where? Citation please.

Comment: As with most engineering decisions, [better](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54766/umem-alloc-3malloc.html) in some attributes, worse in others.

Comment: I know is SunOS library. I thought is alternative of Jemalloc and TCMalloc. Thanks.